# How to make 1-month ahead forecast using ugarchforecast

Tags: r

I'm trying to make 1-month forecast for returns_180 using GARCH(1,1) model and rugarch package. Here is my code:

```
ugarch_spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0),include.mean = TRUE),
                          distribution.model =  "norm" )
fit = ugarchfit(spec = ugarch_spec, data = returns_180,solver = 'hybrid')
forecast = ugarchforecast(fit,data = fit,n.ahead = 30)
```

Unfortunately, I get first 2 points and after that all points are equal

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. GARCH(1,1) very quickly converges to unconditional variance. See for example [this tutorial](http://cims.nyu.edu/~almgren/timeseries/Vol_Forecast1.pdf)

Comment: But, still if I change mean.model to ARMA(1,1) I get almost the same results. I think that it should give different results for ARMA(1,1)/GARCH(1,1) but it doesn't. I still get constant values

Comment: I am trying to predict values not volatility

Comment: Well with GARCH we usually model voalitility, as long as you use it on residuals of some financial data, which you dont specify in the question. The values are then the volatility...I will have a look in the `rugarch` documentation later